# How hard is it to navigate D&D 5e copyright and licensing?

Tags: dnd-5e, tools, intellectual-property

I'm developing the concept of a website to help DMs run campaigns. Imagine a beefed up D&DBeyond site. I'd like to be able to have spells and classes on said site for a few games, but does anyone know how Wizards of the Coast have responded to that being on a website in the past? I know Fandom had all of them on their site for quite awhile.

Comment: Are you planning on only providing SRD content or the full array of content?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Neorequiem! Just to make sure I understand correctly, is the entirety of what you are asking "What D&D 5e content can I host on a 3rd party site?". If so, I might recommend [edit]ing your title and body to clearly reflect that.

Comment: Also what do you mean spells and classes "from a few games" are you planning on hosting non-5e content on there as well?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a hobby project, or one that earns money?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Molot, I don't think WotC care about that distinction. If you're posting non OGL content, they'll tell you to take it down regardless.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "navigate" - if you want to avoid getting an angry letter from their lawyers, you'll have to get a license to host their content. Good luck with that.